# Terminal starting with "no such file or directory:" message on OS X

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, zsh

After installing/uninstalling homebrew and other command line software such as zsh, I had an issue with my command line prompt, which let me to remove several configuration files such as .bashrc, .bash_profile, .zprofile, and .zshrc. Now every time I start my Terminal I show the following. I'm on OS X 10.8.4.

```
Last login: Tue Aug 20 07:59:07 on ttys000
/etc/zprofile:source:2: no such file or directory: /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: This is one of the very clear error messages `;)`: Remove or comment (`#`) line 2 in `/etc/zprofile` which reads probably `source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh`.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for the help, it worked marvelously :)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution than the crude approach proposed in my comment:

If you need to source a file from your `.zshrc` or some other profile file, it is good practice to check if this file exists in order to prevent such error messages ("no such file or directory").

```
[[ -f /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh ]] && source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
```

`-f` checks if `/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh` is a file. If true the part after the logical **AND** (`&&`) gets executed.

Now you don't get an error message on systems the file isn't present, but on systems where is does exist it gets sourced. This is very valuable when you share your `.zshrc` on different machines!